# How to load an image using LWJGL

Tags: java, image, lwjgl

I've Googled a lot and could not find the answer to this. I know how to load an image, I need to load images that aren't 256 by 256 or a direct power of 2.

Like how could I load an image that's 128 by 384 or something like that.

What I'm using now:

Load an image:

```
    public static Texture cow = loadTexture("res/cow.png");

    private static Texture loadTexture(String file){
        try {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", new FileInputStream(new File(file)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now to draw it on a 3D poly face:

```
            txt.bind();
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        {
            //GL11.glColor3d(lightLevel, lightLevel, lightLevel);
            GL11.glColor3d(l, l, l);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1,y1, z1);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+(x2-x1), y1,z1);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+(x2-x1), y1+(y2-y1), z1+(z2-z1));
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1,y1+(y2-y1),  z1+(z2-z1));
        }
        GL11.glEnd();
```

Now that works perfectly, I just need to load images that aren't a power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use slick2d, it is way easier to use and works with lwjgl! All you have to do is:

```
    Image title = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer Gc, StateBasedGame Sbg)
        throws SlickException {

    /**
     * Images
     */

    title = new Image("gfx/main_menu/title/new_title.png");
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer Gc, StateBasedGame Sbg, Graphics G)
        throws SlickException {

    /**
     * Background
     */

    G.setColor(Color.white);
    G.fillRect(0, 0, w*s, h*s);

    /**
     * Images
     */

    title.draw(titleY*s,titleX*s);
}
```

Comment: Slick2D is based on LWJGL. So, no way it works with LWJGL. I would not support your decision on recommending slick2D, however, because the dev team no longer updates it. Use LibGDX.